# mongodb nodejs driver transactions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, nosql

I forcefully make an error in my code when insert data in book collection so that I can check transactions is working properly in mongodb node driver but when I run this code no rollback happened. It create a document in user collection and then throw a error but abort not work.

```
const MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;
const URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testapp"

MongoClient.connect( URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
} )
.then( async client => {
    _client = client
    let _db = client.db( 'testapp' );
    let session = _client.startSession()
    session.startTransaction()

    try {
        let info = await _db.collection( 'user' ).insertOne( {
            name: "Anik",
            position: "Full Stack"
        } )

        await _db.collection( 'book' ).insertOne( {
            user_id: info.ops[ 0 ]._id,
            booked: true,
            asdf
        } )

        await session.commitTransaction()
        session.endSession()
        _client.close()

    } catch ( e ) {
        await session.abortTransaction()
        session.endSession()
        _client.close()
        console.log( e.message )
    }
} )
.catch( err => {
    console.log( err )
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a replication set for using transaction with mongodb
2. You need to path `session` in options for all your write operations

```js
const MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;
const URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testapp?rs=myreplicaset"

MongoClient.connect( URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
} )
.then( async client => {
    let db = client.db( 'testapp' );
    let session = client.startSession()
    session.startTransaction()

    try {
        let info = await db.collection( 'user' ).insertOne( {
            name: "Anik",
            position: "Full Stack"
        } , {session})

        await db.collection( 'book' ).insertOne( {
            user_id: info.ops[ 0 ]._id,
            booked: true,
            asdf
        } , {session})

        await session.commitTransaction()

    } catch ( e ) {
        await session.abortTransaction()
        console.log( e.message )
    } finally {
        session.endSession()
        client.close()
    }
} )
.catch( err => {
    console.log( err )
} )
```